# dynamic body jumping out of water object

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

In my game I have my main object, a jetski, which will dive down into water, when the screen is touched. I managed to code the jetski diving down, with Box2d and some buoyancy forces. But when the jetski is under water, it just rises to the water surface and stays there. Short: the jetski isn't jumping. I thought about applying forces as soon, as the jetski is on the surface. The problem with it is that the force would be a constant force ignoring how deep the jetski was (the deeper the jetski was, the faster it should rise and jump out).
Is there any other way of doing this? 
This is the kind of thing I want: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b2t_zMOy5SM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the new informations I gathered out of your comments I guess you have trouble with coding this example...

1. Your body always surfes on the water.
2. If you press a given Button your body should dive down
3. While you hold this button save always the deepness
4. If you release the button: setLinearVelocity to X
5. If you reached the air, apply once linearVelocityForce based on your deepness.

How you implement this is up to you.

As I could see from your video you uploaded to youtube you may have the problem at:
4:
Because I cant see any code you gave to us, I speculate you apply linear velocity in every step, until you reach the air(This results into big amount of linear velocity = teleporting like movement)
or you setTransform your body to a given coordinate.

The simplest idea I can think of, would be to set the linearVelocity to a given amount (try and error, until you're pleased) Because, if you dont dive deeper, you immidiately have maximum upwardspeed, until you reach the air, and at this exact point(5)
you apply a force.

Comment: The problem with this is, that it leads to a kind of teleporting movement... Is it possible to accelerate the body?

Comment: Why teleporting? If it isn't to fast, it shouldnt teleport..   If a jetski comes out of water, it doesnt move longer with fullspeed, just with a bit of speed... like with 10/100.. And than, real physics must be apply. Like jumping on water. I guess you have some problems with apllyLinearImpulse (maybe to often called / to big force)

Comment: I edited the answer, may this helps you more. If you provide us any code, we may can help you more precisely.

Comment: my project is on Github: https://github.com/JoelBrun/JetskiRider... Since I am new to all this programming stuff it might be a little messy... I code the jetski in core/src/com/joelbrun/jetskirider/screens/Gamescreen.java

Comment: As I could guess : your buoyancy controller is a tutorial, maybe copied, completely? Do you do your project from a tutorial?? I just cant figure out, where you say something like "press button down" or so.. Where do you do your input processing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88305/discussion-between-joel-brun-and-keey).